# Property 'handleSelectChange' does not exist on type '' in Ant Design Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

Ant design has a HOC wrapper for forms that is implemented like this:

```
class View extends Component {
  render() {
  return ( <FormItem
                {...formItemLayout}
                label='Country'>
                {getFieldDecorator('country', {
                  initialValue: Company && Company.country,
                })(
                  <Select
                    showSearch={true}
                    optionFilterProp="children"
                    filterOption={(input: any, option: any) => option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
                    placeholder="Select a Country"
                    onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
                  >
                    {countrylist}
                  </Select>
                )}
              </FormItem>)
  }
}

export default compose(
  Form.create()
  ...
)(View)
```

In normal javascript, the this.handleSelectChange works fine, but I'm trying to migrate my project to typescript, and I'm getting:

> Property 'handleSelectChange' does not exist on type View

I tried extending the interface, but I'm not getting it right.  How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that even though Form.create() was being called, the  element isn't wrapping this - it is in a higher component.  There is no need to call Form.create() here, just do it in the form component, and then pass down form as a prop.  Then you can use

```
form.handleSelectChange
```

and that works.